# C# - How to get application settings to load at run time on a second form?

Tags: c#, save, settings

How to add application settings to *second* form at program runtime.
I cannot even get it to work on form load, but really I need them to load at program runtime.
How to achieve this?

In general, I have my application settings working, mostly.
On the main form (the first form I created) They are set to load at program runtime. 
I also have a menu item to load the settings.
I also have a menu item to save the settings.
I do not automatically save the settings.
All work flawlessly.

I created a second form to use for holding other program settings.
Again, I set the to be loaded at program runtime. Actually, they are set to load when the form loads.
I could not find a way to load them at program runtime.
But this is not working. The settings do not load.
They do save using a menu item and I can load them using another menu item.
The start up load settings are identical to the menu load settings so not sure why they do not load.

Have I put them the code in the right place?
How do I get the settings to load at program runtime (not just when the form loads)?

Here is my code. The second form on load event, that is not working is the last item below.

Main form saving settings (working):

```
private void mnuSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rb1024Res.Checked == true)
    {
        Settings.Default["Res1024"] = "True";
    }
    else
    {
        Settings.Default["Res1024"] = "False";
    }
}
```

Main form manually loading settings (working):

```
private void mnuLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Settings.Default["Res1024"].ToString() == "True")
    {
        rb1024Res.Checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        rb1024Res.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Main form settings load at app runtime (working):

```
private void FrmMainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Settings.Default["Res1024"].ToString() == "True")
    {
        rb1024Res.Checked = true;       
    }
    else
    {
        rb1024Res.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

As stated, all that works perfectly.

Second form saving settings (working):

```
private void MnuPrefsSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ChkTips.Checked == true)
    {
        Settings.Default["TipsEnable"] = "True";
    }
    else
    {
        Settings.Default["TipsEnable"] = "False";
    }
}
```

Second form manually loading settings (working):

```
private void MnuPrefsLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Settings.Default["TipsEnable"].ToString() == "True")
    {
        ChkTips.Checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ChkTips.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Second form settings load at app runtime (**Not** working):

```
private void FrmPreferences_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Settings.Default["TipsEnable"].ToString() == "True")
    {
        ChkTips.Checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ChkTips.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try Settings.Default.TipsEnable.ToString() ?

Comment: Thanks. I tried it on form load and it does not work. I tried it on the menu item and this again works, as per my original code. I am thinking this is not possible? Maybe i will just extend my original form and load all the additional preferences I need at the bottom of it. I just prefer them on a second form.

Comment: It does not work and what happens? Throwing exception? ıf so, what is the exception message?

Comment: No error. It just does not load the settings when I run the app or open the second form.If I use the menu item to load the settings this works. The code is identical to the on load code.

Comment: I have extended the main form and put the controls on there. All working, so going to delete the second form and forget about using one.

Comment: You need to use an instance of the form.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: Thanks. I have moved the controls to the main form for now. They are working with Application Settings now. A checkbox is getting checked unchecked correctly. The actual checkbox change code is not working though. Trying to use it to enable/disable tooltips but whatever I do, they remain enabled. When/if i figure how to fix this I will look at your code for for two forms. Thanks again.